# How to set the size and initialize a map to zero in c++

Tags: c++, maps

I am declaring a map such as `map<string,int> registers`.  How can I set it to a specific size and how can I set all its values to zeros, so that I can later insert values in the mapped value?

Comment: why do you want to do that? why not simply use `m["abc"] = 1;`?

Comment: so i cant use a for loop or something instead of writing all the contents of the map

Comment: What exactly do you want to initialize to zero? map's default constructor creates empty map. You may increase map's size only by inserting elements (like `m["str1"]=0` or `m.insert(std::map<std::string,int>::value_type("str2",0))`).

Comment: @Shadi: You can write the contents of the map in `for` loop if you want. :) What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: It's also worth noting that `map["key"]` will return 0 (and insert "key" into the map) if "key" is not in the map -- so, the values will all be zero when you access them the first time

Comment: I am required to intialise all the maps values to zero and then later on from functions, certain values in the map will change value but the rest stays zero

Comment: @Shadi - Conceptually they all **are** zero. Like Naveen and Cameron say, as soon as you access an element with `m[key]` it will be zero. You don't have to do anything!

Comment: What does "set it to a specific size" even mean? The "size" of a map is the number of key-value pairs it contains. You could put 30 keys in it to start, but which keys should they be, and why? I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this thing works...

Answer (score 23):

How about this:

```
std::map<std::string, int>   registers; // done.
                                        // All keys will return a value of int() which is 0.


std::cout << registers["Plop"] << std::endl; // prints 0.
```

This works because even though `registers` is empty. The operator [] will insert the key into the map and define its value as the default for the type (in this case integers are zero).

So the sub-expression:

```
registers["Plop"];
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (registers.find("Plop") == registers.end())
{
    registers.insert(make_pair("Plop", 0));
}
return registers.find("Plop").second;  // return the value to be used in the expression.
```

This also means the following works fine (even if you have not defined the key before).

```
registers["AnotherKey"]++; // Increment the value for "AnotherKey"
                           // If this value was not previously inserted it will
                           // first be inserted with the value 0. Then it will  
                           // be incremented by the operator ++

std::cout << registers["AnotherKey"] << std::end; // prints 1
```

Comment: This makes things very convenient :)

Answer (score 5):

> how can i set it to a specific size
>   and how can i set all its values to
>   zeros

This is probably much more of a conceptual problem than a syntax/"how to" problem.  Yes, it's true that just by initial access with a given key, that corresponding value is going to be created and set to 0 by default as many posters/commenters said.  But an important phrase that you used that doesn't fit is:

> all its values

It has no values to begin with and if you're programming with the assumption that it does, this alone can be cause for conceptual errors.

It's typically better to be in the habit of finding whether the key is in your map and then, if not, do something to initialize it.  Even though this might seem like just overhead, doing things explicitly like this will likely prevent conceptual errors in the future, specifically when you try to access a key's value without knowing whether it was already in the map.

One line summary:  don't you want to initialize the value yourself rather than having map assign its default value for any given key's value?

Thus the code you probably want to use is:

```
    if(mymap.find(someKey) == mymap.end())
    {
        // initialize it explicitly
        mymap[someKey] = someInitialValue;
    }
    else
    {
        // it has a value, now you can use it, increment it, whatever
        mymap[someKey] += someIncrement;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In map every key is mapped with default value zero when the map is declared.
But if you want to initialize with some value you can follow this approach.
For Structure,

```
struct Node {
   int value = 1;
}
```

For Map with every key mapped to default value 1.

```
Map < int, Node > M;
```